# how to remove carriage returns within xml in unix

Tags: python, xml, unix

I have an xml file that i'm trying to process using python

I am getting errors  as occassionally some of the text within the xml strings have forced carriage returns within them

How do I remove these carriage returns in unix within the xml text without removing all of them because that would mean joining all the xml records together

Example of a xml script that I can parse:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz"><message = 'hello world, i am not going to add a cariage return right now'></message></script>
```

Example of a xml script that I can't parse due to carriage returns:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><script startAt="2015-03-25T20:59:38Z" sessionId="xyz">
<message = 'hello world, i am going to add a cariage return
right now
even though
i do not have to'></message></script>
```

My final output after parsing is going to look something like:

```
script_dt, session_id, message
2015-03-25T20:59:38Z,"xyz","hello world, i am not going to add a cariage return right now"
2015-03-25T20:59:38Z,"xyz","hello world,i am going to add a cariage return right now even though i do not have to"
```

Comment: What differentiates the carriage returns you want to keep and the carriage returns you want to remove?

Comment: You should explain your input data by posting sample text.

Comment: ideally i want one row of data per xml. I.e. remove the carriage returns within the xml but don't remove the ones at the end of the line which indicates a new xml/row

Answer (score 2):

You can remove carriage returns & proceed with XML pretty printing

XML pretty printing can be achieved by using 
`xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s).toprettyxml()`

#### Removing carriage return & new line characters

```
perl -i -pe 's/\r\n//' xmlfile.txt
```

#### Reformatting the file with xml pretty print

```
cat xmlfile.txt | python -c 'import sys;import xml.dom.minidom;s=sys.stdin.read();print xml.dom.minidom.parseString(s).toprettyxml()'
```